# Hiding second vertical scrollbar in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

**Take a look at the site:** [printnil.com](http://printnil.com/collections/all)

It works on chrome and firefox.

Internet Explorer breaks the layout with a second vertical scrollbar.

How to hide the vertical scrollbar in IE?

```
.st-container,
.st-pusher,
.st-content {
  height: 100%;
}

.st-content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.st-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `overflow-x: hidden` from `html` removes the vertical scrollbar in IE.

This is a simple solution, but I'm curious if you had a purpose for that rule in the first place - I'm not seeing anything overflowing laterally that would justify having this rule in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In IE you can hide the scrollbar with the following line.

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Comment: Battle the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: This fix is a classic fix that should instantly relieve any scroll-bar issues in IE. Helped me many times.